# May vs Might in Sentence

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

> On an average Sunday, you might find yourself

In the sentence above, the possibility of the person reading finding themselves doing what it says is pretty high. It's almost certain. Should I use *may* instead? *Might* still sounds better when the sentence is read.

I often find sentences where *may* might be more appropriate but *might* sounds better. Even in this previous sentence I used *might* even though what I'm describing is much more likely than not.

Comment: If "the possibility of the person reading finding themselves doing what it says is ... almost certain", I wouldn't use *might* or *may*.

Comment: Zen, even if grammar books still recognize some difference between 'might' and 'may', it is a fact that in modern English you can use them interchangeably without any difference in meaning and nuance. The same is for 'can' and 'could'. Also 'shall" is no longer in use. And it is better to not say of 'ought'. Summarizing, in concrete, you have only these modals: do, can, should, will and must. Stop.

Answer (score 4):

The [OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/may) has this to say

> Traditionalists insist that one should distinguish between may
>   (present tense) and might (past tense) in expressing possibility: I
>   may have some dessert if I’m still hungry; she might have known her
>   killer. However, this distinction is rarely observed today, and may
>   and might are generally acceptable in either case: she may have
>   visited yesterday; I might go and have a cup of tea.On the difference
>   in use between may and can, see can1 (usage).

the upshot is, do what you like.

Answer (score 3):

*May* versus *might* in a sentence?

**Ia.  Some people follow the rule that *may* can be considered a greater possibility than *might*.**

> “They both indicate that something is possible, but something that may
>   happen is more likely than something that might happen.”
>   [Quick and Dirty Tips](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/may-versus-might?page=all)
>
> “’May’ simply states the possibility or likelihood, while ‘might’
>   emphasizes the conditional nature of the possibility, introducing a
>   greater level of uncertainty.”
>   [After Deadline NYT](http://afterdeadline.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/07/14/may-might-muddle/?_php=true&_type=blogs&_r=0)

**Ib. However, in practice most people use may and might interchangeably in most cases.**

> “Often we read that *might* suggests a smaller possibility that *may*,
>   there is in fact little difference and *might* is more usual than *may*
>   in spoken English.”
>   [English Grammar secrets](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/maymight/menu.php)

**IIa. May can be considered permission**

Example: “Mother may I visit my friend?
 "You may.”

**II b. It is recommended to prefer *might not* over *may not* for clarity because *may* can be considered "permission"**

> According to Garner’s Modern American Usage (a bible for all grammar
>   nuts like me), you should never use “may” in a negative hypothetical
>   because the reader could read it to mean the person “does not have
>   permission.” For example, saying “I may not go to the store” could be
>   misread as “I am not allowed to go to the store.” In this case, you
>   always use “might”: I might not go to the store.
>   [Writer's Digest](http://www.writersdigest.com/editor-blogs/questions-and-quandaries/grammar/may-vs-might)

**III. It is recommended to prefer *might have* over *may have* for a hypothetical that didn’t happen**

Example: when using “may have” and “might have” you can use either if the truth of a situation is still unknown (i.e. "I think your comment *may have* / *might have* offended some people"), but if the truth of the situation is known and you are speaking about a hypothetical alternative that did not occur, it’s clearer and more common to use “might have” (i.e. "If Brazil’s best player hadn’t been hurt, they might have won the World Cup").

**IVa. Historically different tenses:**

> In historical practice for the usage of these words some people used
>   “may” exclusively for present tense and “might” exclusively for past
>   tense
>   [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/may-or-might)

**IVb. Modal usage most commmon today**

Today the words *may* and *might* are used as modals like *would*, *should* and *could*, meaning that they are generally used without regard to their historical tense and the modal used should reflect a slightly different meaning.

**IVc. Even today, especially for some situations involving past tense, many people feel *might* is still not always interchangeable with *may* in normal usage.**

For instance, because it sounds awkward to mix past tense and present tense, many people including myself would probably prefer “after I read that book, I knew I might visit London one day” to using 'may' (but if someone did use 'may' I could live with it, just wouldn't prefer it).

On the other hand, I find “Last night the weatherman said it may rain today” acceptable, especially because whether it will rain is something that is still an unknown.